# Creating a social network account without consent

Tags: privacy, social-media, natural-person

One of my colleague that does not want to be on any social network was a bit harassed by another colleague that treat him of paranoid.

So this other college start to create a Facebook account with lot's of personal information of my first colleague, name, work, photo etc... 
And he start to add some friends that he knows they know each other, well you see the point.

My colleague does not want to be on Facebook but does not even have the password of the account. What can he do? Is that impersonation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impersonating someone else on Facebook is against Facebook's TOS. It could also be a criminal offense, depending on local/national jurisdictions. Someone who is being impersonated on Facebook can file a complaint with Facebook; see [How do I report an account or Page that’s pretending to be me or someone else? | Facebook Help Center | Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/174210519303259/). If it is a criminal offense, depending on local/national jurisdictions, a local prosecutor will need to be involved.

Comment: For the completeness of my questions, what about other social media? Like Instagram, twitter, tiktok etc... ? Did they have similar TOS ?

Comment: They all should; check each TOS and look for a link on each site for a complaint procedure.